# Why Google Charts always overflows?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I'm digging google for an hour now, to find out why google chart api makes it's parent dom to overflow.

Scrollbars appear every time I draw the chart

[image: Scrollbars appear every time I draw the chart]

As you can see there is no padding or margin. When I use default settings for `chart.draw()` I got the same result.

[image: As you can see there is no padding or margin]

How can I make the chart to just fit in it's container? 
(`overflow: hidden` is not a good solution here, because the chart itself also overflows and I don't want to cut it off)

Thank you in advance for any help!

## Update: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5ALk/)

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example?

Comment: Sure, I'm going to set up a jsfiddle :) 10 min

Comment: I find that `overflow-y: auto;` does not shows scrollbar without google chart, but does with it. Confusing :/

Comment: I managed to hide scrollbars by just removing `overflow-y: auto;`, but  a question still remains: Why `overflow-y: auto;` adds scrollbars when it's not needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case the problem is basically that you specify a height to `#chart`, and set it to `overflow-y: auto`. This will cause the vertical scollbar to appear, and since you set the `width: 100%`, and the vertical scrollbar takes space, a horizontal scrollbar appears. Remove the `overflow-y: auto` declaration and you're good to go. I suggest you remove the `height: 350px` as well

Comment: Thank you, especially for the explanation!